# Choosing a Set of r elements from a set having n elements.

Tags: combinatorics, contest-math

Define a set     $X$={$1$,$2$,$...$,$n$}  .
Determine the number of ways of selecting a subset of $X$ such that it contains no consecutive integers .

Comment: Hint: Think about stars and bars. Think about stars and star-bars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $a_n$, be the number of subsets satisfying the condition, including the empty set. By adding one more number to the set, the subsets that can be obtained in this new set are:

- all that could be obtained in the previous one, that is $a_n$;
- all that could be obtained with the first $n-1$ elements with the number $n+1$ included, that is $a_{n-1}$;

With this we have the recursive relation $a_{n+1}=a_n+a_{n-1}$. As $a_1=2$ ($\emptyset$ and $\{1\}$), $a_2=3$ ($\emptyset$, $\{1\}$ and $\{2\}$) we obtain the recursive relation defining the Fibonacci sequence $F_n$ (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) with just a displacement of indices. So the desired number of subsets is $a_n=F_{n+1}$. The explicit Binet's formula for $F_n$ can be seen in the link.

PS: if it the recurrence realtion was not the Fibonacci sequence, there would be no problem. See this link (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving) for solving linear recurrence relations.

Comment: +1 for the clear explanation. I think you should add in the empty set, and so the answer is $F_{n+1}$. This would also take care of the set ${n+1}$, which arose from adding $n+1$ to the empty set.

Comment: Thank both of you Mateus Sampio and Calvin Lin for the solution of my problem.But is there a general formula for determining the nth term of a Fibonacci Sequence?

Comment: Check out the wikipedia link Adhiraj, there is some nice information about determining the nth term.